# Pyarrow Dataset read specific columns and specific rows

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

Is there a way to use pyarrow parquet dataset to read specific columns and if possible filter data instead of reading a whole file into dataframe?

Comment: Yes, to reading specific columns, that's one of the strengths of the Parquet format.  In general, with `pd.read_parquet()` you can specify the columns with the columns arg.  

To my knowledge you can't filter on load.

Comment: You can also filter a dataset when reading, but for now only in case of a partitioned dataset (consistent of multiple files in nested directories, see the `filter` argument in the docs https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.read_table.html). To also filter within a single file is being worked on (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1796)

Comment: See also the aswer to this file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56522977/using-predicates-to-filter-rows-from-pyarrow-parquet-parquetdataset/56562285?noredirect=1#comment99829368_56562285

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of `pyarrow==2.0.0`, this is possible at least with [**`pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset`**](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset.html).

To **read specific columns**, its `read` and `read_pandas` methods have a `columns` option. You can also do this with `pandas.read_parquet`.

To **read specific rows**, its `__init__` method has a `filters` option.

Comment: Excellent! Hmm I wonder if all rows are read into memory before filtering out the bad ones. If so, the memory pressure still spikes. though i bet the arrow table is smaller than the pandas df