# Can I filter a parquet table?

Tags: python, parquet

I am just starting to look at parquet files, since some of my data is available in that format. And I haven't really played with it before, so here's my question.

I open my parquet file like this:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

table1 = pq.read_table('mydatafile.parquet')
```

And this file consists of 10 columns. Is it now possible, directly from this, to filter out all rows where e.g. column3 has the value 1?

I mean, I could just do:

```
df = table1.to_pandas()
df = df[df["column3"] != 1]
```

But can this be done natively, without converting to a Pandas data frame first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this syntax from the [documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.read_table.html)

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

table1 = pq.read_table('mydatafile.parquet', filters = [('column3',  '!=' , 1)])
```

### Source:

[Using predicates to filter rows from pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56522977/using-predicates-to-filter-rows-from-pyarrow-parquet-parquetdataset)

Comment: How would you incorporate an 'and' query?