# how can i read a specific page of a parquet file? use python or java

Tags: python, java, parquet

Now I know how to read a parquet file in row group granularity.
such as:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pp
_table = pp.ParquetFile(file)
row_group_contents = _table.read_row_group(row_group_index, columns=[column])
```

but i want to read in page granularity. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filters` parameter like:

```
filters=[('column', '=', 'value')]
```

some useful sources:

[official docs](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset.html)

[stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56522977/using-predicates-to-filter-rows-from-pyarrow-parquet-parquetdataset)

Comment: Thank you very much. But I wasn't trying to filter the data.
As far as I know, parquet file currently provides index at page granularity.（https://blog.cloudera.com/speeding-up-select-queries-with-parquet-page-indexes/）
I would like to know if there is a way to locate a page directly.
For example, read the 2nd page of the 1st column of the 1st row group directly.